# How to convert nested string dictionary without quotes to dictionary in Python

Tags: python, json, string, dictionary

I have below nested string dictionary without quotes which I want to convert into python dictionary.

```
                { id: 0,
                  label: 'Data0',
                  axis: "left",
                  color: "#0000ff",
                  avg: "383.04347826086956",
                  last: "378.0",
                  min: "282.0",
                  max: "439.0" }
                ,
                { id: 1,
                  label: 'Data1',
                  axis: "left",
                  color: "#00ff00",
                  avg: "",
                  last: "",
                  min: "",
                  max: "" }
```

Expected Output:

```
                { "id": 0,
                  "label": "Data0",
                  "axis": "left",
                  "color": "#0000ff",
                  "avg": 383.04347826086956,
                  "last": 378.0,
                  "min": 282.0,
                  "max": 439.0 }
                ,
                { "id: 1,
                  "label": "Data1",
                  "axis": "left",
                  "color": "#00ff00",
                  "avg": "",
                  "last": "",
                  "min": "",
                  "max": "" }
```

The main reason for doing this is am getting output as string from API response where it contains many other things which I had removed by using split() method.

Comment: Where is that coming from? It's not valid as Python _or_ JSON.

Comment: Is this API using a known format? You may find you need a fairly complex parser for this.

Comment: I think to would help if you show an example of the actual response - i.e., before you started tampering with it. As @tdelaney has said, if it's not a natural fit for Python then you'll probably need to develop a custom parser. Good luck with that

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a "nested string dictionary". Is that just a python string? Or are those python dictionaries using the values from python variables named "id", "label", and etc... If its a single python string you are trying to parse, put all of that in python triple quotes so we know.

Comment: Please find the actual raw output which I am getting
https://pastecode.io/s/x8uxaudc
Here I want to extract the summaryData

Comment: @RibhujeetDas - So, you are trying to parse javascript source in python? That's not an API response, its the code that generates the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
js_data = """
/*
 * Pure Javascript, which calls the specified callback function, specified using the Jsonp parameter
 *
 * Callback function is passed all parameters necessary to render chart
 */

MP.ChartController.loaded('chartdiv',
{
    error: '',
    width: 1480,
    height: 308,
    summaryData: [

        {
            id: 0,
            label: 'Data0',
            axis: "left",
            color: "#0000ff",
            avg: "383.04347826086956",
            last: "378.0",
            min: "282.0",
            max: "439.0"
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            label: 'PQ Initiated',
            axis: "left",
            color: "#00ff00",
            avg: "",
            last: "",
            min: "",
            max: ""
        }
    ],
    graphType: 'chart',
    warnings: []
});
"""

import re
import json

# find `summaryData`
summary_data = re.search(r"summaryData: (\[.*?\]),", js_data, flags=re.S)

# add quotes("") around keys
summary_data = re.sub(r"(\S+):", r'"\1":', summary_data.group(1))

# replace ' to "
summary_data = summary_data.replace("'", '"')

# decode the string:
summary_data = json.loads(summary_data)

print(summary_data)
```

Prints:

```json
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "label": "Data0",
        "axis": "left",
        "color": "#0000ff",
        "avg": "383.04347826086956",
        "last": "378.0",
        "min": "282.0",
        "max": "439.0",
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "label": "PQ Initiated",
        "axis": "left",
        "color": "#00ff00",
        "avg": "",
        "last": "",
        "min": "",
        "max": "",
    },
]
```

Comment: This solution is data dependent. if a value has a time value like `12:20:00`, it doesn't work. But sometimes that's what data hacking is about.